# Mocking package private classes

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

Using Mockito or another similar framework. Is there a way to mock a package-private class?
I am trying to test my service layer mocking my DAO classes. The problem is that the DAO instances are package private and only can be obtained through a factory.

```
MyPackagePrivateDao mockedDao = mock(MyPackagePrivateDao.class);
```

The compiler says that the class cannot be accessed from outside the package.
Do you have any example?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible with Mockito, it requires to modify the bytecode of the actual class. This is not a planned feature.

Don't you have interfaces that you could eventually mock for these DAOs ?

Another option is to look on PowerMock which is great to deal with legacy code, ie when the software design is forcing you to mock statics, private, final, etc.

Comment: I do have interfaces. I didn't know that I can mock the interfaces instead the implementation classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, your problem is that your SUT (and therefore its test) is in a different package from the class that you want to mock, otherwise there wouldn't be a problem.

The way I would solve this is to write a static utility method in the test class for the class that you want to mock.  This utility method should just create and return a mock of the desired class, which it can do because it's in the right package.  You can then call the utility method instead of calling `mock(MyPackagePrivateDao.class)`.